# Differences in path encoding between Mojave and High Sierra

Tags: mojave, path, r

I have a script (in R) where I specify the path to some data. The script ran on my computer's High Sierra. After updating to Movaje, I get "path non-existent" error messages so my script no longer runs.

So I:

1. Use the Terminal to go to the folder I want
2. Copy-paste the path from the Terminal to my R script. I see no differences between the two bits of text, but Mojave seems to see something. My old line doesn't run, the new one -copied from the Terminal- does.

I can work with this, but would like to understand, where could the differences be?

Comment: What exactly is this path??

Comment: "~/Dropbox/1_SUBFOLDER/2_SUBFOLDER/analysisElisa/ROIsAllToolboxes/"